# Access silverlight control name in Javascript

Tags: silverlight

I have a text box in which i enter some random text. I have a java script function named FormatText(control-name,command). Inside this java script function i need to access the text box's text property so that the text can be formatted depending on the command that is passed( eg bold,italic,underline). **Hence i needed to know whether there is any way to access a control's name through javascript**

Comment: Why don't you do the formatting from within the Silverlight control?

Comment: Are we talking about a silverlight application delivered in a Xap or a chunk of Xaml to be rendered by the silverlight plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it directly, but you can access JavaScript from within Silverlight, so you can do something like this:

```
using System.Web.Browser;

HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("myFunction", new string[] { textBox.Name });
```

This will invoke `myFunction` with the name of the TextBox as it's parameter.

[Source](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/09/calling-javascript-functions-from-silverlight-2.aspx)

So when you initialise the control you could call this to get the name into your JavaScript.

Comment: @Madhur2479 - can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5686282/edit) your question with a complete description of the problem you are trying to solve. That way people will be able to provide better answers.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. So i think it is not possible to access the textbox.text property from javascript right?

Comment: @Madhur2479 - There is *some* interaction, but without knowing exactly what you want to achieve any answer will be general.

Comment: OK i will start with my complete requirement. I have a text box in which i enter some random text. I have a java script function named FormatText(control-name,command). Inside this java script function i need to access the text box's text so that it can be formatted. depending on the command that is passed( eg bold,italic,underline). Hence i needed to know whether there is any way to access a control's name through javascript

Comment: @Madhur2479 - **EDIT** your question with this information! Comments aren't meant for this sort of thing.